# Creating dynamic UI in Kentico CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, dynamic, kentico

I have created a static UI in Kentico CMS and now i want to make it dynamic. I don't have the backend code yet. Is there any possible method using which i can create a dynamic UI without using backend client code ? Please suggest me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamic`?

Answer (score 0):

Kentico provided a bunch of UI templates that you can build a crud (create read update delete) of your custom classes pretty easily.

You usually do have to generate they classes code files, but using object listing, edit/new object, and the vertical tab templates you can build most if what you want to do with touching code.

And you can always check out Kentico's existing modules and see how their UI pages are configured, although some user custom interfaces.
https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/creating-custom-modules#Creatingcustommodules-Buildingthemoduleinterface

Answer (score 0):

In order for some of the properties to display your custom class values you will need to have the code generated for those classes and placed in the file system.  It's the only way Kentico knows those classes properly exist.  It compares the database with the classes registered in code and then allows them to display.  What I'm referring to is the class list when you configure your listing or editing templates for objects.

Our typical process is to create all the classes in the module first, then generate the code after all the classes are created to have a one time recompile vs. multiple times.